# Block sqlite step until database is no longer busy

Tags: c++, sqlite

When using sqlite library for C++, a call to `sqlite3_step` on a `sqlite3_stmt` can fail in several different ways. As far as my understanding goes, all of them but one should result in an exception or are caused by programming errors.

One, however, puzzles me a bit: `SQLITE_BUSY`. I mean: `SQLITE_BUSY` just means that the database is locked because some transaction is already taking place on it, right? Say that some different process has begun a transaction and has not committed or released it yet, any call to a `sqlite3_step` trying to edit the database or to begin a new transaction will fail with `SQLITE_BUSY`.

However, this doesn't look like an error to me: when a resource is being used, I can... just wait! Not unlike a mutex (maybe of a more complicate nature) I guess, it should be possible to block the execution of the current thread / process until the access to the shared resource is available again.

Is there a way to do such a thing? What I would like is something in the form:

```
sqlite3_step_or_block_until_available_then_step(my_stmt);
```

So that the execution is blocked until the database is no longer busy and I can use it. Is there a solution provided by sqlite library itself? If not, what could I do? I mean, I can obviously busy wait until the `SQLITE_BUSY` error is no longer returned, but it doesn't really make sense as it consumes a lot of resources. Are there more performing ways to achieve this?

If possible, please provide some short example so that I can understand how to get this to work!

Comment: You should be providing your own locking mechanism around accesses to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You could lock the database yourself with the use of mutexes, but sqlite3 does [provide a mechanism that *might* help](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy) (emphasis mine):

> SQLITE_BUSY
>   The SQLITE_BUSY result code indicates that the database file could not be written (or in some cases read) because of concurrent activity by some other database connection, usually a database connection in a separate process.
>   For example, if process A is in the middle of a large write transaction and at the same time process B attempts to start a new write transaction, process B will get back an SQLITE_BUSY result because SQLite only supports one writer at a time. Process B will need to wait for process A to finish its transaction before starting a new transaction. **The `sqlite3_busy_timeout()` and `sqlite3_busy_handler()` interfaces and the `busy_timeout pragma` are available to process B to help it deal with SQLITE_BUSY errors.**

You can [register a callback to handle `SQLITE_BUSY`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html) so instead of the database returning `SQLITE_BUSY` it will invoke your handler. There are limitations to this you can read about in the link.

I won't provide an example for this because I feel it is less likely to solve your problem of [having multiple threads access a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214960/managing-sqlite-database-in-a-multithreaded-environment) since you can only have one busy handler per database connection.

If, like I suspect from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214960/managing-sqlite-database-in-a-multithreaded-environment), you have control over all the code accessing the database, then it might just prove easier to use `std::mutex` or `std::conditional_variable`:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(dbMutex);
    sqlite3_stmt(...);
}
```

Comment: That only works if you're the one blocking the database (ie same process, or all processes controlled by you), but that might not be the case.

Comment: @Blindy if multiple processes could be accessing the database that one does not have control over, then one could use the mechanism provided by sqlite (which I mentioned in the answer)